# Expressing $b^x$ as $e^{x \ln b}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Can anyone explain the following equality please?

$$b^x = e^{x \ln (b)}$$

I've verified it with values but I can't think of what the proof for this would be.

Comment: Hint: $e^{x \ln(b)}=(e^{ln(b)})^x$.

Comment: Proof of what? That is the **definition** of $b^x$.

Comment: At most, it is reasonable to ask why with such a definition the usual properties of powers (like $b^x\cdot b^y=b^{x+y}$ and $b^x\cdot c^x=(bc)^x$) are preserved for real exponents and positive bases.

Comment: Another version of @dxiv's hint: $$\operatorname{e}^{x\ln(b)} = \operatorname{e}^{\ln\left(b^x\right)}.$$

Comment: Short answer.  If we assume $b^x =y$ has values fo all real $x $ then $\log_b y$ is defined to be the value $x$ so that $b^x=y$ and we define $\ln y=\log_e y $.  $e^{\ln b}=e^{x} $ where $x$ is the number so that $e^x=b $ which means.... $e^x=b $.  Long answer; we have to do quite a bit of work to determine/define that $b^x=y $ actually makes sense and has a solution for all real x and y.

Answer (score 3):

Following @dxiv's comment, we have the following:

1. By definition of logarithm,
   $$b=e^{\ln b}$$
2. So, 
   $$b^x = (e^{\ln b})^x$$
3. Using that, for any real numbers $a,b,c$, we have
   $$(a^b)^c=a^{b\cdot c}$$
4. We arrive to
   $$b^x\ =\ (e^{\ln b})^x\ =\ e^{x\cdot\ln b}\,.$$

---

Also note, that - as @Jack D'Aurizio commented - usually this formula is the **definition** of the exponential $b^x$ for *general* real numbers (for *rational* exponent $x$, we can extend the familiar definition, but for real exponents we need to use either limits or this formula).

Comment: Please be more careful; your point (3) is **false** for $(a,b,c) = (-1,2,\frac12)$ and **meaningless** for $(a,b) = (0,-1)$.

Comment: And point (1) is meaningless for $b = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$b^x=e^{\ln(b^x)}=e^{x \ln b}$$

Having used the properties $x =e^{\ln x}$ (exponential and natural 
logarithm are the inverse function of each other) and the property of the logarithm $\ln(a^b)=b \ln a$.

Answer (score 0):

$$b^x = e^{x \ln (b)}$$ take $\log_{b}{} $ both sides
$$\large \log_{b}{b^x} = \log_{b}{e^{x \ln (b)}}\\$$
$$x\large \log_{b}{b} = x \ln (b).\log_{b}{e}\\ \to
x\large \log_{b}{b} = x \frac{1}{\log_{b}{e}}.\log_{b}{e}\\
x \times 1=x \times \frac{\log_{b}{e}}{\log_{b}{e} \\x=x } \checkmark$$